# Redux—global error handler

Tags: error-handling, redux

I am running redux on node. To handle asynchronous actions, like reading a file or listing of a directory, I am using `redux-thunk` in combination with Promises. So a typical action can look like that:

```
const
  fs = require('fs'), 
  { promisify } = require('util'),
  readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

const listFiles = dir => dispatch => 
  readdir(dir)
    .then(files => dispatch({ 
      type: '…',
      payload: { files }
    }));
```

So:

```
try {
  store.dispatch(listFiles('/some/path'));

catch (error) {
  //some rescue plan here,
  //won't work if directory not exists

}
```

wont work here, because the action is asynchronous and right now, the only way I see to handle all errors is to add a `.catch()` to all promises in all actions and dispatch an error action there.

That has two downsides:

1. a lot of code repetition and
2. i need to know all possible errors in ahead.

So my question is: Is there any way to create a global error handler, which will also be called if an asynchronous action fails, such that I can add some error indicating information to the state, which can be displayed?

Could that be possible with a »storeEnhancer« or some »middleware«?

**UPDATE**

I could find something that is really helpful:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log(reason.message);
});
```

That callback is triggered whenever a Promise is rejected and no catch block is added. Right now that seams to do the trick, but anyway, I would prefer a solution that basically does the exact same thing, but only for rejected Promises which are triggered within `store.dispatch()`, so only when an error within the processing of actions/middleware/reducers within redux comes to happen.

Comment: Look at [Promise.prototype.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

Comment: @OriDrori That is a good Idea, but hacking the `prototype` feels kind of a pain, because I might probably change more than I want. AKA internals of Node??

Comment: You don't need to hack the prototype. Go to the link, and see how the catch for promises works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a redux middleware solution, take a look at [`redux-catch`](https://github.com/PlatziDev/redux-catch).

Comment: That's an »Error catcher middleware for Redux reducers and sync middlewares «, but i am also concerned about async actions…